# multiplication of two inputs on java using a wrapper

Tags: java

I am recently learning Java from EDX and in one of the activities,I was asked to write a programme to get two inputs from the user ,multiply them  and output the result.In the code I have not used the scanner method because a class wrapper was provided to be used for output and input function.I think I did everything correctly but my code is not running,what could be the problem??? 
Here is the code

```
// I was only  required to write the body,the method had been provided 
 int x,y;
double Answer;
IO.output("Enter an integer, x: ");
x = IO.inputInteger;
IO.output("Enter an integer, y: ");
y = IO.inputInteger;
Answer = x * y;
IO.outputln("Answer = " + Answer);
```

This are the errors I get

Compilation Error(s):

```
[ERROR] cannot find symbol, symbol: variable inputInteger, location: class comp102x.IO.
[ERROR] cannot find symbol, symbol: variable inputInteger, location: class comp102x.IO.
```

Additional Comments:

```
The submitted code might use a variable before it is declared or there may be a typo mistake on the variable name. You may check spelling and letter cases of the identifiers.
There might be some other reasons for the compilation error.
```

Comment: I would assume that `IO.inputInteger;` should be `IO.inputInteger();` Also, please respect Java variable naming conventions (`Answer` should be `answer`).

Comment: If Elliott's suggestion does not fix your problem, could you try including the error message you are getting? If you are not getting an error message, is it doing anything at all?

Comment: I have edited it and added the error message I was getting @rp.beltran

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'll look at it and see if I can find anything, but if you made Elliot's edit, adding the parenthesis then nothing is popping out at me yet, but he was definitely right that those were needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only problem here, as Elliot Frisch suggest in his comment was that you forgot to add parenthesis after your call to IO.inputInteger. Without the parenthesis, `IO.inputInteger` refers to the function, not to the value returned by calling it. It is like saying "output the process of getting the integer from the user" instead of "output the integer you get from the user".

This would make your corrected code:

```
int x,y;
double Answer;
IO.output("Enter an integer, x: ");
x = IO.inputInteger();
IO.output("Enter an integer, y: ");
y = IO.inputInteger();
Answer = x * y;
IO.outputln("Answer = " + Answer);
```

My initial thought was perhaps additionally IO may have needed to be instantiated, but I found what appears to be the documentation for it at http://w02.hkvu.hk/edX/COMP102.1x/Javadoc/comp102x/comp102x/IO.html and it confirmed for me that this is not the case as `IO.inputInteger` and `IO.outputln` are both static functions which means that you they are called from their class, not from an instantiated object of the class type.

The IO class is unique to the course you are taking, I looked around for a download somewhere but could not find one, but I tried to reproduce your code as accurately as possible using only standard methods, and I got this:

```
Scanner IO = new Scanner(System.in);

int x,y;
double Answer;
System.out.println("Enter an integer, x: ");
x = IO.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter an integer, y: ");
y =  IO.nextInt();
Answer = x * y;
System.out.println("Answer = " + Answer);
```

Which outputs:

```
Enter an integer, x: 
5
Enter an integer, y: 
9
Answer = 45.0
```

And this further validates what seemed clear, that there is not an issue with any of your logic in the program.

If I remove the parenthesis to recreate your original syntax, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    nextInt cannot be resolved or is not a field
    nextInt cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

Which reads very similarly to your error.

The point of being so thorough here, because surprisingly enough, I had one, was to say that if problems persist, then there is a second problem somewhere, and that the error has to relate to the IO class quite directly, or an error in some omitted section of the code.

Comment: It still not compiling

Comment: Getting these errors                                                                                              
Compilation Error(s):

    [ERROR] cannot find symbol, symbol: method nextInt(), location: class comp102x.IO.
    [ERROR] cannot find symbol, symbol: method nextInt(), location: class comp102x.IO.

Additional Comments:

    There might be a typo mistake on the method name. You may check spelling and letter cases of the identifiers.
    There might be some other reasons for the compilation error.

Comment: Are you use the code from the first segment, the second one with nextInt() is for if you were using a scanner instead of EDX's IO. If you are using the first one, there may be a bug in EDX's  IO class, or it is not getting setup right.

Comment: Also, what environment are you using to write your code? Are you using clips, or netbeans or something? Or is it EDX specific?